# Invalid Request upon trying run in simulator

Tags: appcelerator

I cannot seem to run anything via iOS simulator in appcelerator today:

STUDIO BUILD: 4.7.0.201607250649

> SDK :5.4.0 (have tried a few different sdks versions)

When trying to run I get:

> [INFO] : Alloy compiled in 0.65622s [INFO] : Alloy compiler completed successfully [ERROR] : invalid request

That was for existing projects...

When I tried a new project I got a message stating:

The project has an invalid/non-platform GUID. and cannot be run. Would yo like to register the app with the platform, updating its GUID?

Upon clicking yes it does nothing to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Invalid Request` seems to trigger when there is an issue with your authentication with Appcelerator.

Go to terminal a log in again: `appc login`.

All should work after you've logged in.

Comment: thank you...logging out via terminal and logging seems to have got  it working. phew:)

Comment: Me too - had to logout then login via terminal and fixed.